How to get what the user entered in Contact Form 7 and change it before sending?
How to get what the user entered in Contact Form 7 and change it before sending? I have an input field, when the user submits the data I have to validate it and if there is anything to change, I tried many options but couldn't find what I need.
For example, user write something, I need to compare it with JS variable, and change it in sending.
For minimal instance:
You need Wordpress, plugin ContactForm7, and for JS I used WoodySnippets.
Create Contact Form with two fields and button.
<label>Doesn't need[text* text-564 placeholder ""]</label>
<label>Need[text* text-276 id:myform "5"]<label>
<button onclick="coinsCheck()">
<label>[submit "Submit"]</label>
</button>

and:
<script>
    myfor = document.getElementById("myform").value;
    function coinsCheck(){
        alert(myfor);
        if(myfor !== '6'){
            alert(myfor);
        }
    }
</script>

Here I output the variable, the first time just to know the value, the second time if it is not equal to 6.
But alert shows "null" twice(if snippet above form) or four times "[object HTMLInputElement]" if snippet below the form. And in console I have this error: Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects: http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/459d16a800ceb49fe2871a22c7041252?s=52&d=mm&r=g

why do you want validation on client side and not on server side ? and what must append when the value is not valid ? edit your question to answer to that.

You have multiple problems:

you want to get the value of your form, whereas your form has no value, but form elements, which have value on their own
you probably have an input element whose value you are interested about, but that's missing from your code chunk, so I added such an input
you get the value you are interested about outside the function and never refresh, so, putting aside that you get the wrong value, you are also getting it at the wrong place, not during form submission, but before anything
since the form never had a value, it is undefined, which is why you see undefined the first time and, since undefined is not '6', you will see it a second time as well

Here's a tweaked code, where I have a numeric input I am getting the value of during form submission and compare it to '6'. I presumed that you do not event want to submit the form if this value is not '6'.


let myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
    function coinsCheck(){
        alert(myinput.value);
        if(myinput.value !== '6'){
            alert(myinput.value);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
<form id="myform">
<input id="myinput" type="number" value="5">
<label>Doesn't need[text* text-564 placeholder ""]</label>
<label>Need[text* text-276 id:myform "5"]<label>
<button onclick="return coinsCheck()">
<label>[submit "Submit"]</label>
</button>
</form>



But if you wanted to change it to 6, then you can change the code like this:


let myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
    function coinsCheck(){
        alert(myinput.value);
        if(myinput.value !== '6'){
            myinput.value = 6;
        }
        return true;
    }
<form id="myform">
<input id="myinput" type="number" value="5">
<label>Doesn't need[text* text-564 placeholder ""]</label>
<label>Need[text* text-276 id:myform "5"]<label>
<button onclick="return coinsCheck()">
<label>[submit "Submit"]</label>
</button>
</form>



